# Apply the same movement to all spawn prefabs(with List)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The script spawn **unlimited** moving walls created by prefabs(Cubes) with  **InvokeRepeating** .How to put the spawn prefabs in the List at the Runtime and stop them if them collide with the Player?

Wall

[image]

```
public Vector3[] positions=new Vector3[4];
public GameObject barrier;

float speed=1f;

void Start () 
{
    InvokeRepeating("SpawnBarrier",1f,speed);
}

void SpawnBarrier()
{
    for(int i=0;i<=3;i++)
    {
        Instantiate (barrier,positions[i],Quaternion.identity);
    }
}


void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if(other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        Debug.Log ("Trigger");  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new script for `Movement` and attach it to your barrier prefab which contains `OnTriggerEnter` method and a `static event Action` :

```
bool canMove = true;

void OnEnable()
{
    PlayerTriggered += StopMoving;
}

void OnDisable()
{
    PlayerTriggered -= StopMoving;
}

void StopMoving()
{
    canMove = false;
}

void Update()
{
    if(canMove)
        // movement code
}

public static event System.Action PlayerTriggered;
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if(other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        if(PlayerTriggered != null)
            PlayerTriggered();
    }
}
```

Comment: It will be applied to all walls(prefabs) or only the prefab that collides with the player?

Comment: To all the walls

Comment: It's not working,are you sure that it works with InvokeRepeating?

Comment: where did you attach the script?

Comment: To the prefab! And wrote if  canMove then gameObject.transform.Translate(0f,0f,-0.7f)

Comment: it will only move when player triggers any of the barrier

Comment: If the prefabs are moving and I press from the inspector canMove=false they are still moving !

Comment: Ohhh, but I want conversely))

Comment: What are you trying to do anyway? Be clear on what you want to achieve so I can help you :)

Comment: I wrote what Im doing, the prefabs are moving ,and when the player will collide with the prefabs I want it to stop them!

Comment: Anyway,I think I should put all spawn prefabs in the List!

Comment: Your comment in the code says the otherwise. Check the updated code

Comment: Yeah, my fault,I mean there to apply the stop movement!

Comment: Anyways my updated answer should work for you. If you want to stop spawning when player triggers the barrier. Just add `CancelInvoke()` in StopMoving method

Comment: I'd recommend you to watch some tutorials from Unity and learn basics :)